# : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

Me podrían apoyar con el siguiente error por favor, estoy iniciando en la programación y me he topado con ésto.

> : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Ingresa un dia de la semana:    at curso1.pkg2.Curso12.main(Curso12.java:20)
C:\Users\Antonio Hernandez\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

```
package cursojava1;

/**
 *
 * @author Antonio Hernandez
 */
public class Ejercicio4 {
    
       public static void main(String[] args){
        
       System.out.print("Ingresa un dia de la semana:");
       int dia=Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
       
       String DiaSemana;
       
       switch(dia){
       
           case 1:
               DiaSemana= "Matematicas";
       break;
       
          case 2:
               DiaSemana= "Biologia";
       
       break;
       
          case 3:
               DiaSemana= "Ciencias";
       
       break;
       
          case 4:
               DiaSemana= "Fisica";
       
       break;
       
          case 5:
               DiaSemana= "Civismo";
       
       break;
       
          case 6:
               DiaSemana= "No hay materia";
       
       break;
       
          case 7:
               DiaSemana= "No hay materia";
       
       break;
       
          default:
              DiaSemana="No existe ese dia";
       
       }
       
       System.out.println("Dia"+dia+":"+DiaSemana);
       
       
       }
    
}
```

Comment: Hola, @Antonio. ¿Te ha servido de ayuda la respuesta proporcionada? ¿Has solucionado? Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Antonio:

Esto sucede por la siguiente línea de código:

```
int dia=Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
```

Esto suele suceder si ejecutas el programa en un IDE que no tenga consola para introducir datos.

Hay varias formas de leer la entrada de datos de un usuario, por ejemplo la clase Scanner )o te preocupes por el tema de clases ahora mismo, si estás comenzando, más adelante verás clases y lo comprenderás facilmente, por si aún no lo has visto).

Importando la clase de la siguiente forma:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

De esta forma podrías instanciar el objeto Scanner, recoger la entrada de los datos y luego convertirlos a int:

```
Scanner objetoScan = new Scanner(System.in);
String entradaDatos = objetoScan.next();
int dia = objetoScan.nextInt();
```

Podrás hacer uso de el método in para obtener entrada de datos.

El código completo sería:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Ejercicio4 {
    
       public static void main(String[] args){
        
           
       Scanner objetoScan = new Scanner(System.in);
       String entradaDatos = objetoScan.next();
       int dia = objetoScan.nextInt();
   
      
       String DiaSemana;
       
       switch(dia){
       
           case 1:
               DiaSemana= "Matematicas";
       break;
       
          case 2:
               DiaSemana= "Biologia";
       
       break;
       
          case 3:
               DiaSemana= "Ciencias";
       
       break;
       
          case 4:
               DiaSemana= "Fisica";
       
       break;
       
          case 5:
               DiaSemana= "Civismo";
       
       break;
       
          case 6:
               DiaSemana= "No hay materia";
       
       break;
       
          case 7:
               DiaSemana= "No hay materia";
       
       break;
       
          default:
              DiaSemana="No existe ese dia";
       
       }
       
       System.out.println("Dia"+dia+":"+DiaSemana);
       
       
       }
    
}
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.